# From where should I start Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, programming

I want to know how to start from scratch for Machine Learning. Also which language is best for implementing its algorithms or developing future applications based on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a book person so I would recommend one of the following books:

1. Elements of Statistical Learning (Hastie and Tibshirani).
2. Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (Bishop).

The first book is available as a free download from the authors' website. You may download and start reading it. You will get an idea about your deficiencies. If it's too difficult, then you need to improve your statistics and linear algebra skills. For Linear Algebra I recommend:

- Linear Algebra and its Applications (David Lay).

For statistics I like:

- Discovering Statistics (Andy Fields).

Stay away from the recipe books if your aims are long-term.

Answer (score 2):

You can start learning machine learning by attending the lectures of Andrew Ng at Coursera. This course helps you to develop basics as well as advanced concepts in machine learning.
Following is the link to the course:
[Machine Learning by Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)

Start learning Python for implementing algorithms related to machine learning.