# Which language to learn for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scala

I am currently working in BigData with Spark-Scala framework. I want to learn Machine learning from scratch.
Which language would be better to learn for machine learning, Scala or Python?

Comment: Check this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/from-where-should-i-start-machine-learning . This could be thought as an opinion based question, but I would recommend python too for the reasons that Feliz describes. One more point would be that the transition is easy from whatever language you have background on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done only a little bit of scala (spark streaming for database replication), but have worked with python for about a year. I would recommend python for the following reasons:

- We do a lot of notebook centric development at my job. I would recommend that because the Jupyter IDE allows you to visualize/debug your data really effectively, which is important to understanding and validating concepts.
- Python is dynamically typed and has a powerful set of built-ins and utilities that will let you transform your data into the shape you need pretty easily.
- Python has first-class support for almost all ML libraries (TensorFlow, PyTorch, Sci-kit Learn).

Comment: Thanx Feliz..That explanation gives much clarity.!! :)

Comment: Can you also tell me some source which will be good to learn Python intended for Machine Learning.?

Comment: To be honest, I ended up having to pick it up on the job. One talk I found to be exceptional was by David Beazley about "builtin superheroes". Very relevant in my day to day when it comes to cleaning, aggregating, and grouping of data for analysis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyDLAutA88s